# Swift UITableView NSFetchedResultsController crashing when moving the last item in section to new section

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift3

So I've got a similar issue in multiple projects now relating to NSFetchedResultsController updates. I am working on playing around finishing off the unfinished features at the end of the Mark Price SomeJunk tutorial app. I have my sections set up automatically thru the FRC. Using the store name as the section name. If there is only 1 item associated with a store section, and i reassign that store to another store name, leaving the section empty, I'm getting crashes.

`Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  no section at index 4 with userInfo (null)`

This was not a topic covered during the course when I took it, so I'm kinda usure which way to go with this now?    Here is a link to my project, Thanks : https://github.com/jwilkins728/SomeJunk

Comment: Where does the crash occur

Comment: Sort by store using the segment bar. Then take ANY store with only one item, edit that item, and change the store to something else, leaving the original store section empty.